# Regularization term moving the hyperbolic plane

Tags: machine-learning

When we train a network, we usually have an error function which usually looks like this:

$$Error = (output - target)^2$$

When we add a regularization term, it looks something like this:

$$Error = (output - target)^2 + reg term$$

I understand that there are many different ways of defining the reg term, but in this example, we can make it the sum of all weights.

When we do this, are we just not moving the hyperbolic plane up and down? The slope of it should stay the same everywhere and thus not really make a difference in finding a minimum of the error function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the regularization term is usually to keep the network from overfitting by keeping the weights vector with low absolute values or sparse. Therefore I would say a sum of all weights is not a good regularization term, because even extreme positive and negative weights can sum to zero. In the regularization term, the $L_2$, $L_1$, $L_0$ norms are commonly used (read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics))).

In a side note, if I understood you correctly, I would suggest to avoid imagining the target function (or loss function) as a hyperbolic plane, since usually DNNs contain non linear activation functions like [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)).

Answer (score 2):

Regularization terms should increase with model complexity, cost, or other undesirable factors.  Then when the model's optimized, the optimizer is forced to consider the trade-off between getting a better fit and avoiding additional complexity/cost/etc..

For example, imagine that you're doing a multi-linear regression with 20 different independent variables.  Often, you can remove one independent variable without hurting the overall $R^2$ value of the correlation much.  If you don't use regularization of some sort, the optimizer would still include all of the independent variables anyway just to get the best fit.  But if you penalize the model for using more data, then the optimizer may start to zero-out independent variables that didn't really help.

With neural networks, regularization terms often penalize for increased weights.  This is because weights of $0$ effectively remove neural connections, resulting in a simpler model.